# Display runtime variables within Debug console in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I've switched over from IntelliJ to WebStorm to do some front-end development and I seem to have lost the ability to view the runtime variables.  Can someone point out the configuration to allow me to do this?

When I'm debugging, currently I see this:

[image]

When I used to see similar to:

[image]

Simply, I've lost the Variables tab. Can anyone help me configure the options? I've tried using https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Inspecting_Variables.html 
...to no avail

Thanks in advance

Comment: To those who found this on Google like I just did: **make sure your program is stopped at a breakpoint**. The link above says: ***When the program is suspended**, you can inspect variables and arguments (…)*. You can also see breakpoints on both screenshots here, but this may not be obvious to those who are new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This view should definitely be there. Please try restoring the **Debug** tool window layout by pressing the corresponding toolbar button:

[image]

does it help?
If it doesn't, please contact JetBrains support, providing your *idea.log* (**Help | Show log in Explorer**) and information about Node.js version being used